# Finding the position (index value) an element of a bst would be in if it was in a sorted array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a function that finds the nth smallest element of a bst, I wanted to try to find a way to find the "index" an element would be in if the bst was converted to an array.

This is my attempt so far

```
    int find_position(bst_node* r, int x) //x is the target
    {
        if(r == nullptr)
            return -1;

       if(r->val == x)
           return r->numLeft;

       if(r->val > x)
           return find_position(r->left, x) ;

       if(r->val < x)
           return find_position(r->right, x) + r->numLeft + 1;
    }
```

This seem to return the proper numbers, i couldnt find a pattern in the return values other than they increase as x increases

Comment: Pass in a counter and start incrementing.

Comment: @SegFault What is r->numLeft? Show the definition of the binary tree.

Comment: If `x` is the index that you are looking for, then why are you comparing it to `val`?

Comment: x is the value at the target node

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its the number of elements in the left sub tree, should have specified sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this efficiently, you need to record the size of each subtree at each node of the BST.
Here is a BST with the cached sizes in parentheses:

```
                 20 (8)
               /    \
             /        \
           10 (4)      30 (3)
          /  \          / 
         /    \        /
       5 (2)  15 (1)  25 (2)
         \           /
          \         /
           8(1)    22 (1)
```

- Note that if x = 20 (at the root) then return the size of the left subtree (4 in this case); *be careful here* : if the left subtree is empty return 0 (the size of an empty tree).
- If x < 20 then simple recurse on the left subtree
- If x > 20 then recurse on the right subtree but add 5 (the size of the left subtree + 1) to the returned number (if it is found).
- Apply this logic at each level of the tree.
- If you reach an empty tree, return -1 as sentinel that the value was not found.

This is what your code is attempting to do, but has a few issues.
Here is patched version that handles edge cases you missed and stores
the size in each node (instead of storing `numLeft` which is a little
weird):

```
int find_position(bst_node* r, int x) //x is the target
    {
        if(r == nullptr)
            return -1;

        if (r->val == x)
            return r->left == nullptr ? 0 : r->left->size;

        if (r->val > x)
            return find_position(r->left, x) ;

        if (r->val < x) { // this if is superfluous
            int pos = find_position(r->right, x);
            if (pos == -1) return -1;
            int leftSize = r->left == nullptr ? 0 : r->left->size;
            return pos + leftSize + 1;
         }
    }
```

Comment: i have numLeft and numRight to track the size of each sub tree separably, but ill give this a try, does this return the index number or just the number in it appears if we did an in order traversal? ik its just a difference of 1 but the + 1 on the return for the last if statement confuses me

Comment: Instead of storing the sizes of the subtrees, it is more natural to just store the size of the tree.
Order of return values is: 0 for the first element, 1 for the second, up to N-1.

Comment: The + 1 comes from the fact that you have to include the root node in counting all the previous elements.